# System can't find file specified on visual studios 2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I can't figure out what I did wrong, keeps saying it cannot find the specified file. Seriously can't figure this out

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    string name;
    double courseNumber;
    double hoursWorked;
    const double payPerHour = 8.25;


    cout << "What is your name and what is your course number? " << endl;
    cin >> "Name " >> name >> " CourseNumber " >> courseNumber;
    cout << name << "Welcome to the C++ course numbered " << 
    courseNumber << endl;

    cout << "How many hours did you work this pay period? " << endl;
    cin >> hoursWorked;
    cout << name << 
    " You worked " << hoursWorked << " hours at " << 
    payPerHour << " per hour. " << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Oh and I did add the brace at the end

Comment: Have you moved it from its original location?

Comment: Yes I have, I have tried redoing it so many times :(

Answer (score 1):

```
 cin >> "Name " >> name >> " CourseNumber " >> courseNumber;
```

Remove those strings from cin it should work fine.

Comment: did you interrupt any visual studio update? does command line compiling work(from developer command prompt for visual studio)

Answer (score 0):

Please add these 2 pieces of code to the file (here I will call the 2 initial files when creating the project MainProject) MainProject.cpp:

```
#include "MainForm.h"

using namespace System;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;

[STAThread]
int main(array<String^>^ args) {
    Application::EnableVisualStyles();
    Application::SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    FirstCppProject::MainForm form;
    Application::Run(% form);
    return 0;
}
```

and MainProject.h (GUI code file)

```
#pragma once

namespace FirstCppProject {
    public ref class MainForm : public System::Windows::Forms::Form {
    public:
        MainForm() {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

    private:
        System::Void InitializeComponent() {
            this->SuspendLayout();
            // Initialize other components here
            this->ResumeLayout(false);
        }
    };
}
```

Then save and run the program again (Build -> Build Solution)